# Using Tomcat Maven plugin with multiple servers

Tags: maven-2, tomcat

I've looked at the [usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/usage.html), but haven't understood from it how to configure multiple servers. I added separate `server` elements to settings.xml - but I don't understand how to specify a different URL for every server.

The URL element belongs to the global plugin configuration. How do I configure multiple server URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine the documentation of the Tomcat plugin you will see that it does not support multiple <configuration> sections. That should be a small addition because in the deploy phase you only copy the WAR file to the server using an HTTP PUT command. So I wonder why they have not added this capability to the plugin.

Anyhow, one possible workaround is to:

1. Make multiple copies of your pom.xml in the same directory but give them unique names, e.g.  dev_1_pom.xml, or dev_<some_machine_name_or_IP>, qa_1_pom.xml ..... You can keep your development pom.xml file name the same because you will likely still run Maven from the command line. Personally, I prefer running the **mvn** command from my IDE (a button click away vs. typing an **mvn** command with arguments every time).
2. In each of the copies, change the <configuration> section under your Tomcat plugin to point to a different server that matches the name of your specific pom.xml. You will need corresponding  sections in settings.xml
3. Create corresponding **External Tools Configuration(s)** (Eclipse, or other IDE) and each one call the corresponding POM file. Here is an example with Eclipse:

   Open External Tools Configuration Dialog in Eclipse (either from the dropdown menu next to the button, or by going to the menu bar and clicking Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations). Then on the Main Tab, provide values for the following fields

       Location: C:\downloads\tools\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\mvn.bat
       Working directory: `${workspace_loc:/<project_name>}` - replace <project_name> with the name of your project
       Arguments: **-f <pom_file_name>** <other_arguments> - <other_arguments> could be tomcat7:redeploy

   Now you can run these external tool launchers individually to deploy to different servers.
4. Optionally, extract the **mvn** commands from your launchers and create a shell script (batch or Unix bash script) that runs all of them. That way you can deploy to multiple servers at once. You can also run this script from Eclipse. Create a new External Tools Configuration launcher but this time your Location: field will point to **cmd** (Windows) or **bash** (Unix, Linux ...), not **mvn**

Answer (score 6):

You could add multiple profiles to your `pom.xml`. One for each server. Check the [Maven documentation on profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for details!